# Setting up a Screen Cron for a User

Tags: centos

I'm running [supybot](https://github.com/ProgVal/Limnoria) on CentOS 6, and need it to start on reboot.
What I've done is setup a cron for the user to run in a screen, but the bellow doesn't seem to be working
I tried [what they've suggested](http://config%20supybot.pidfile%20/home/%3Cusername%3E/%3Cbot%3E/%3Cbot%3E.pid) on their website, but 'config' is not a command, and ./config in the directory doesnt work

```
crontab -u danny -e
-------
@reboot /bin/sleep 25 ; /usr/bin/screen -dmUS supy /home/danny/startup/supy.sh

supy.sh
--------
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/danny/supy/ && supybot sup.conf
```

Comment: Prob Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/danny/supy/ && /home/danny/.local/bin/supybot sup.conf
```